# Fastest method of playing audio from YouTube with Python

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

I am wondering what's the fastest way to play/stream audio from YouTube with Python. I am trying to make a home "smart" audio player with a raspberry pi and python and have been able to make it grab the url of the youtube video I want to play, and play it. Although, it is very slow taking over 20 seconds on my raspberry pi. I have tried using [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/), and [Pafy](https://pypi.org/project/pafy/) but both options are not fast enough. Any ideas?

Comment: What pi are you using? Could be the speed of the pi not the libraries you are using.

Comment: If you are only concerned with audio, consider using the `bestaudio`, `worstaudio`, or `worst` format for youtube-dl, to see if discarding the video or at least reducing its quality will speed things up a bit.

Comment: exactly WHAT is taking 20 seconds? downloading the video? you should probably stream it then, instead.

Comment: @TheTesseract'sShadow I have a raspberry pi zero w, and yes it is slow, but I ran the same code on my pc and it was within 5 seconds difference of the raspberry pi.

Comment: @IrmendeJong It is taking 20 seconds to download the video, not grab the url.

Comment: @DillonDavis I will try that, thanks

Comment: @Daquaney well then, don't download the whole video first, stream the data as required. In my own audio player 'm using ffmpeg to do the actual audio decoding, but otherwise, it is 100% python and works just fine with just a few % cpu usage

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It could be on the raspberry pi's end, i would recommend just streaming the songs through a different platform. If you must check out changing your youtube-dl command from the default "youtube-dl -f bestaudio --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 5 " to a lower audio quality, m4a, and trying bestaudio, worstaudio, and worst audio formats.